# PHP/CSS If page is loaded on mobile, only display JPG background

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mobile

So for my site, I'm using PHP to call a random gif to be the background. On mobile, this can be quite resource intensive. How can I make it so that when a person loads the site on mobile, it only displays 'static01.jpg'.

PHP code for calling background:

```
<?php $bg = array(
    'page01.gif', 
    'page02.gif', 
    'page03.gif', 
    'page04.gif', 
    'page05.gif', 
    'page06.gif', 
    'page07.gif', 
    'page08.gif', 
    'page09.gif', 
    'page10.gif', 
    'page11.gif', 
    'page12.gif', 
    'page13.gif', 
    'page15.gif', 
    'page16.gif', 
    'page17.gif', 
    'page18.gif' 
); 
$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); 
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; 
?>
```

CSS Background Code:

```
    background-image:
    linear-gradient(to top,rgba(64,58,89,0.478),rgba(64,58,89,0.478)),
    url(<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the background code under a class and use a media query to change the background image based on the screen size.

```
.random_background {
  background-image:
  linear-gradient(to top,rgba(64,58,89,0.478),rgba(64,58,89,0.478)),
  url(<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>);
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
  .random_background {
    background-image: url('static01');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override CSS rule:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(to top,rgba(64,58,89,0.478),rgba(64,58,89,0.478)),
        url('static01.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, almost all the devices with width under 767 px is considered like mobile.
You could use CSS media-queries

```css
  .your-bg-container { background-image:
    linear-gradient(to top,rgba(64,58,89,0.478),rgba(64,58,89,0.478)),
    url('selectedBG.gif');
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
       .your-bg-container{
        background: url("/static01.jpg");
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using media queries and a mobile first approach would be the best way.

So first of we apply a background image that will apply for mobile and up, until we decide to overwrite it at a larger breakpoint.

```
.main-bg {
   background-image:
    linear-gradient(to top,rgba(64,58,89,0.478),rgba(64,58,89,0.478)),
    url(static01.jpg);
}
```

Now we decide to apply the image from the array at 768px and up:

```
@media(min-width:768px){
.main-bg {
   background-image:
    linear-gradient(to top,rgba(64,58,89,0.478),rgba(64,58,89,0.478)),
    url(<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>);
  }
}
```

and in our html we add `.main-bg` to the body or whatever div or element you are targeting.

```
<body class="main-bg">
```

So now, any mobile that is smaller than <768px will never load in the background image that is referenced in the array.